# Kotlin weird print shortcut

Tags: kotlin

I'm a little confused. In my Picture you see that I can print things by only writing the string. But it prints no such statement except the last one. Could sb explain to me this behave. Thanks in advance.

```kotlin
var a: Int = 42
var b: Int = 1337
a=b
b=a
println("a: $a")

"a: $a"
"a: $a"
"a: $a"
"a: $a"
"a: $a"
```

```
a: 1337
a: 1337
```

I expected to get printed all written strings.

Comment: It looks like this code lives in some kind of a notebook. Software like Jupyter notebook usually print out the last expression in a cell.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there might be a misunderstanding regarding how printing works in Kotlin. In Kotlin, when you use println("a: $a"), it prints the value of a along with the string "a: " to the console.

However, in the provided code snippet:

```
var a: Int = 42
var b: Int = 1337
a = b
b = a
println("a: $a")

"a: $a"
"a: $a"
"a: $a"
"a: $a"
"a: $a"
```

The lines "a: $a" without a println statement are just string literals, and they are not actually printed anywhere. If you want to print those strings, you need to use println for each of them:

```
println("a: $a")
println("a: $a")
println("a: $a")
println("a: $a")
println("a: $a")
```

This will print the value of a along with the string "a: " five times. In your provided output, you see a: 1337 printed because of the last println("a: $a") statement, which actually prints the value of a after the previous assignments. The other lines with just the string literal are not printed, as they are not part of any print statement.

I hope this clarifies the behavior you're observing. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask!